# Including script reference from HtmlHelper extension method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is the sample extension method for calendar:

```
public static string Calendar(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    return "<input type='text' onclick='showCalendar(this)'/>";
}
```

Function showCalendar() is defined in calendar.js.

Is it possible to register a reference to calendar.js from an extension method?

Html.Calendar() could be called more than once, but only one script should be included.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: YES.

Here comes the But...

But you need to change your return type. if you just return a string, it will be encoded so you browser wont actually run the script block.

In Chrome you get somthing like this "" notice the quotes. to get round this use IHtmlString as your return type, and to make double sure return helper.Raw.

```
public static IHtmlString RegisterScripts(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        return helper.Raw("<script>function () { DO SOMETHING }</script>");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice question.. for the time being I just make another extension method from which I return the script registration (say, RegisterCalendarScriptBloc()) but it would be better to have an automatic inclusion the first time a dependency is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this if you are using WebForms Views (**not tested**):

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public static string Calendar(this HtmlHelper html, HtmlHead head)
{
    var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);
    var url = urlHelper.Content("~/Script/calendar.js");

    //var scriptControl = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
    //scriptControl.Attributes.Add("src", url);
    //scriptControl.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");

    //if(head.Controls.Contains(scriptControl))
    //{
    //    head.Controls.Add(scriptControl);
    //}

    // or

    if(!head.Controls.Cast<Control>().Any(x => (x as HtmlGenericControl) != null
        && (x as HtmlGenericControl).Attributes["src"] == url))
    {
        var scriptControl = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
        scriptControl.Attributes.Add("src", url);
        scriptControl.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");

        head.Controls.Add(scriptControl);
    }

    return "<input type='text' onclick='showCalendar(this)'/>";
}
```

In View:

```
<%= Html.Calendar(Header) %>
```

Hope this works **:)**